# Storing more than one string in a MySQL Database Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Before I ask my question, I just wanted to thank everyone that replied to my question yesterday -> [Countdown using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662369/countdown-using-javascript).

**Idea:**

I created a quiz using php, but I would like to create a MySQL Database and having a table with all the questions, answers and multiple choice stored inside.

**Issue:**

Since the quiz is multiple choice, I don't know how to go about storing the multiple choice options in the table. Could I store the options and have each answer separated by a special character and let php get the string and separate the options?

Ex: Question: What is your favorite color? Options: Blue=Red=Purple=Yellow.(Database View)

What do you folks think is the best practice for something like this?

Comment: Kingkero has the correct answer, for further reading search "relational database design" and "normalisation"

Comment: @DavidB where is the normalization on his answer? how will it handle question with multiple answer?

Comment: In general terms if you think commas eperating values in a table is s good idea then you should read about relational database design, and if your readign about that then you shoudl be reading about data normalisation. As stated above kingkero has the answer, I was attempting to provide some useful fuerther reading. What have you contributed with your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best practice would be to use multiple tables. One for the question and one for answers. The `answer` table would contain `question_id` as well as a flag whether or not it is the correct answer

It could look like this

```
TABLE questions
FIELDS: id, text

TABLE answers
FIELDS: id, question_id, text, correct
```

The problem with using one field for all the answers is that you could accidently use the character you use for splitting inside the text of an answer

Comment: Yes.  Don't store encoded values in a single database field, it will make your life a living hell when doing reports.

Answer (score 2):

simply, create two tables:

- questions

  question_id, question
- answers

  answer_id, question_id, answer

Now, you can link these two tables using **question_id**

Answer (score 2):

Tables:

**quiz**

```
quiz id (pk)
quiz info (other columns)
```

**questions**

```
question id(pk)
quiz id
question text
```

**answers**

```
answer id(pk)
question id
answer text
```

To display a given question do a join on the quiz, question and answers.

**EDIT**: You could either add a column for 'right/wrong answer (0/1)' or have another table:

**solutions**

solution id(pk)
   question id
   answer id

I didn't put the 'correct answer' in the `answers` table as that's not good normalization.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways around this :

- The "proper" way is to create another table ( so that you have a table called "questions", each of which have a unique id, and another called "answers", where each has the question id )
- The "simple" way, which is to use JSON ( see [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) ) which takes care of using special characters etc in a field

Answer (score 2):

There could be many possible schema designs for this but my suggestion is like this:

**Don't ever store values separated by comma on the tables.**

This table holds the quizzes.

**Quiz Table**

- ***QuizID (PK)***
- other columns..

This holds the questions for every quiz.

**Question Table**

- ***QuestionID (PK)***
- QuestionDetail
- QuizID (FK)
- other columns...

This holds the answers.

**Answer Table**

- ***AnswerID (PK)***
- AnswerDetail

This holds the correct answer for every question on each quiz or in other words, this is the answer key.

**Question_Answer_Correct Table**

- QuestionID (FK) -- also a compound primary key with AnswerID
- AnswerID (FK)

This contains list of users.

**User Table**

- ***UserID (PK)***
- UserName
- other columns...

This contains answer of users on a specified question. There is no `QuizID` here since the questions are already connected on the quiz table.

**User_Answers Table**

- UserID (FK)
- QuestionID (FK)
- AnswerID (FK)

Answer (score 2):

You'd have a `questions` table, like this:

```
id  |            question
0             Do you even lift?
```

`id` would be `INT(11) PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` while `question` would just be `TEXT`. Then, you would have an `answers` table:

```
id  | question_id | answer
0          0         Yes
1          0         No
2          0         Maybe
```

Here, `question_id` refers to the ID of the question in the `questions` table. These answers all belong to one question. This is called a `Has many` relationship, as one question has many answers.

This is how its usually done. Implementing it is not that hard, even if you're not using a framework (most of them do the work for you).

Hope this helps