# Is this good practices for questions and answers?

Tags: mysql

Im about to start a "quiz" project, with questions and answers. And before i start, I just want to check with you experts on how the database design should be.

I have googled, and searched SO and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15681501/4892914), where it should be two tables. One with questions, and one with answers.

```
TABLE questions
FIELDS: id, text

TABLE answers
FIELDS: id, question_id, text, correct
```

I think i will have about 100+ questions from different subject though.

So i was thinking to add a subject row so sorting, and displaying questions from a specific subject is possible, something like this:

[image]

The `question` table will look like this for example:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------------------------+
| id |  subject  |                 text                  |
+----+-----------+---------------------------------------+
|  0 | beer      | what is the best beer in the world?   |
|  1 | mountains | what is the world's highest mountain? |
+----+-----------+---------------------------------------+
```

And `answers` table, were 1 is the correct answer:

```
+----+------+---------------+---------+
| id | q_id |     text      | correct |
+----+------+---------------+---------+
|  0 |    0 | carlsberg     |       1 |
|  1 |    0 | heiniken      |       0 |
|  2 |    0 | root beer     |       0 |
|  3 |    0 | budweiser     |       0 |
|  4 |    1 | k2            |       0 |
|  5 |    1 | Kangchenjunga |       0 |
|  6 |    1 | Mount Everest |       1 |
|  7 |    1 | Makalu        |       0 |
+----+------+---------------+---------+
```

## My question/s:

- Is there another more efficient (or even easier) way of doing things?

Comment: <humor>But Carlsberg isn't the best bear (snow china is I believe by sales volumn) and Mount Everest  isn't even close to the tallest mountain in the world...  it may be the tallest ABOVE ground...  Mauna Kea is tallest from base to summit I believe.</end humor>  while your approach is straight forward it does lead to possible duplication of answers.

Comment: Nice design, though **SUGGESTION:** Add another SUBJECTS table and add subject_id to QUESTIONS table. ( @divix 's mentioned points are not necessary but you can change datatypes (e.g. correct to true/false or 0/1)

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the best solution..

I would suggest to drop column `q_id` from `answers` and create a linking table called like: `questions_to_answers` with columns: `id (int autoincrement), question_id (int), answer_id (int) and correct_answer (tinyint)` instead.

That way you could re-use answers to multiple questions (`many-to-many relationship`) or just have duplicated answers to the same question. It gives you move powerful and robust solution in my opinion.

Comment: This is what I would do.

Comment: sorry my ablity to edit my own comments is really falling apart today :-(

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please provide DB scheme and an example? Not quite sure how the linking table works